# Issue when compilin cpp program on ubuntu's shell

Tags: c++, linux, shell, gcc

So I was trying out the  **Linux C++ compiler**  and this happened while compiling the following code:

```
#include <iostream> 
using namespace std;
int main(){
cout<<"Hello World!\n"<<endl;
return 0;
}  



ceibal@ceibal:~$ gcc HelloWorld.cpp
/tmp/cc78Dkhk.o: In function `main':
HelloWorld.cpp:(.text+0xa): undefined reference to `std::cout'
HelloWorld.cpp:(.text+0xf): undefined reference to `std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::operator<< <std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, char const*)'
HelloWorld.cpp:(.text+0x14): undefined reference to `std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::endl<char, std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&)'
HelloWorld.cpp:(.text+0x1c): undefined reference to `std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >::operator<<(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& (*)(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&))'
/tmp/cc78Dkhk.o: In function `__static_initialization_and_destruction_0(int, int)':
HelloWorld.cpp:(.text+0x4a): undefined reference to `std::ios_base::Init::Init()'
HelloWorld.cpp:(.text+0x4f): undefined reference to `std::ios_base::Init::~Init()'
collect2: ld devolvió el estado de salida 1
ceibal@ceibal:~$ pico HelloWorld.cpp
ceibal@ceibal:~$ gcc HelloWorld.cpp
HelloWorld.cpp:3:1: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘int’
ceibal@ceibal:~$ pico HelloWorld.cpp
ceibal@ceibal:~$ gcc HelloWorld.cpp
/tmp/ccIivRal.o: In function `main':
HelloWorld.cpp:(.text+0xa): undefined reference to `std::cout'
HelloWorld.cpp:(.text+0xf): undefined reference to `std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::operator<< <std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, char const*)'
HelloWorld.cpp:(.text+0x14): undefined reference to `std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::endl<char, std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&)'
HelloWorld.cpp:(.text+0x1c): undefined reference to `std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >::operator<<(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& (*)(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&))'
/tmp/ccIivRal.o: In function `__static_initialization_and_destruction_0(int, int)':
HelloWorld.cpp:(.text+0x4a): undefined reference to `std::ios_base::Init::Init()'
HelloWorld.cpp:(.text+0x4f): undefined reference to `std::ios_base::Init::~Init()'
collect2: ld devolvió el estado de salida 1
```

I tried with the same program but on C and it worked perfectly, but as soon as I translated it to c++ this occurred.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ gcc HelloWorld.cpp
```

This invokes C compiler but your code is in C++. Use `g++` to invoke C++ compiler.

```
$ g++ HelloWorld.cpp
```